# YSlow Primed Cache - Wrong Pie Chart

Tags: statistics, yslow, http-status-code-304

The problem that i have is like this:

I did a YSlow test and under the Statistics Pie Chart View i have a wrong pie chart diagram. The Empty cache displays 11 requests and the primed cache displays 2 requests.

Now one of the two request is a request for a HTML file which the Net Panel shows as 304 Not Modified - but YSlow till shows it in the pie chart as a new request with file size.

Now as far as i know is that if a 304 Not Modified request is made, it shows it under the primed cache listing but with 0.0 KB file size and not in the pie chart.

Is this some bug? Somebody have had some experience?

---- PS: It worked fine 2 hours ago and YES I'm quite sure i did not change any settings ---

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes there can be differences between the Net panel and YSlow components report. See this page on the [YSlow FAQ](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/faq.html#faq_accuracy) that explains some of the reasons why this can happen.

If you add here the URL of the page you're analyzing, a better answer may be possible.